# kdb q - update statement in try catch

Tags: kdb

In q, say someone was naughty and created a function that sometimes returns a table with a mixed-type column:

```
t:([] c1:(`a;"dfdf";`b;"ccvcv"))
```

and sometimes a table with a symbol-only column:

```
t:([] c1:`a`dfdf`b`ccvcv)
```

I want to update `c1` to contain only symbols in a try-catch in case `t`c1` already contains only symbols. But I have a hard time translating the statement

```
update c1:`$c1 from t where 10h=type each c1
```

into the `![t;c;b;a]` syntax which works with the try-catch `@` operator

```
t:([] c1:(`a;"dfdf";`b;"ccvcv"));
c:enlist(=;type each `c1;10h);
b:0b;
a:(enlist`c1)!(enlist `$`c1); / TYPE ERROR
@[![;c;b;a];t;`continue] / this is what I want to do
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `a` should be defined like so:

```
a:(enlist`c1)!enlist($;enlist`;`c1)
```

You can get this by using `parse` on your original `update` Q-SQL statement:

```
q)parse "update c1:`$c1 from t where 10h=type each c1"
!
`t
,,(=;10h;(k){x'y};@:;`c1))
0b
(,`c1)!,($;,`;`c1)
```

Noting that `,` in k is `enlist` in Q

You also need to change your definition of `c`:

```
c:enlist(=;(each;type;`c1);10h);
```

Putting it all together:

```
q)t:([] c1:(`a;"dfdf";`b;"ccvcv"))
q)c:enlist(=;(each;type;`c1);10h);
q)b:0b;
q)a:(enlist`c1)!enlist($;enlist`;`c1)
q)![t;c;b;a]
c1
-----
a
dfdf
b
ccvcv
```

But as pointed out in another answer, best to avoid functional form wherever possible

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's best to avoid functional selects, if your use case permits then `@` amend is a great alternative which can be particularly useful in place of update statements.

```
q)@[t;`c1;{$[10=type x;`$x;x]}each]
c1
-----
a
dfdf
b
ccvcv
```

Or if you still wish to use try-catch:

```
q)@[t;`c1;{@[`$;x;x]}each]
c1
-----
a
dfdf
b
ccvcv
```